# Calculating relative position of points when zoomed in and enlarged by a rectangle

Tags: geometry, rectangles

There is a rectangle, defined by the top left point $R1(0, 0)$ and the bottom right point $R2(200, 200)$ (the $y$ $axis$ is inverted).

In that rectangle, there are some points $P1(100, 100)$, $P2(50, 50)$ and $P3(150, 150)$.

Now there is another rectangle, defined by $R3(25, 25)$ and $R4(100, 100)$.

Here is a picture (sorry for my horrible paint skills):

[image: Picture showing what I explained just before]

So now, I am trying to calculate the coordinates of the points inside the blue rectangle, when rectangle pink is enlarged to the size of the blue rectangle, zoomed in. The points have to still be in their relative location to rectangle pink.

With relative location I mean that if you move one point to the right by $x$, all other points also have to be moved by $x$, so that they always keep the same distance from each other.

Here's what I have so far:

1. Subtract $R3$ from point $P$ (which can be any point $Pn$)
2. Multiply $Px$ with $$\frac{R2x - R1x}{R4x - R3x}$$
3. Multiply $Py$ with $$\frac{R2y - R1y}{R4y - R3y}$$
4. Repeat for every point

It doesn't matter that some points might lie outside of the rectangle (like $P3$).

As far as I know, this works, but maybe I missed something.

---

Now my question is, is this approach correct, i.e. does it *always* work for any points? Are there any flaws, can it be improved? Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Your requirement to transform the pink rect into a new one, which is congruent to the blue rect, is met by infinite many transformations, as we could move the new pink rect anywhere on the screen, and even fiddle with its orientation.

Comment: @mvw Which should mean that there are infinite ways to solve this?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you mean with "The points have to still be in their relative location to rectangle pink " does this mean they have to keep the exact distances, or are they allowed to scale?

Comment: @mvw they can be scaled, but 2 points that were on opposite side in the pink rectangle can't be next to each other in the enlarged rectangle (no counting very small values, where this might happen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are dealing with squares, not rectangles, so scale factor for $x$ is the same as the scale factor for $y$. In fact, the scale factors should be equal if both rectangles are similar.

In terms of pure geometry, I consider this to be 2 transformations, a dilation followed by a translation. In terms of a web page, I would scale each point and then scroll the window to the corner of the pink rectangle.

In either case, the scale factor is $\frac{200}{75}=\frac{8}{3}$. Multiply each coordinate by $\frac{8}{3}$ to achieve the dilation/scaling.

Now R3 is at about (66.7, 66.7), so subtract about 66.7 from the new $x$ and $y$ values of each coordinate to achieve the translation/scroll.

Alternatively, you can to the geometric transformations in the other order (translation first, then dilation). If you do, be sure the amount you subtract from each coordinate is only 25 (the pre-dilation value of R3).